# Tensorflow.js: dtype of the feed (int32) is incompatible with that of the key 'input_1' (float32)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I did a transfer learning from Mobilenet to my model, and trying to do the prediction:

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const image = tf.reshape(tf.fromPixels(img), [1, 224, 224, 3]);
const pretrainedModelPrediction = pretrainedModel.predict(image);
const modelPrediction = model.predict(pretrainedModelPrediction);
const prediction = modelPrediction.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];
console.log({ prediction });
```

It's failing at this line of code:

```js
const pretrainedModelPrediction = pretrainedModel.predict(image);
```

With this error:

```
tfjs.js:67 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The dtype of the feed (int32) is incompatible with that of the key 'input_1' (float32).
    at new t (tfjs.js:67)
    at assertFeedCompatibility (tfjs.js:67)
    at e.add (tfjs.js:67)
    at new e (tfjs.js:67)
    at tfjs.js:67
    at tfjs.js:49
    at e.scopedRun (tfjs.js:49)
    at e.tidy (tfjs.js:49)
    at e.tidy (tfjs.js:49)
    at s (tfjs.js:67)
```

Any idea why is this error happening and how to fix it?

As additional info:

- I'm using `@tensorflow/tfjs` version `0.12.0`
- All the failing code (with the model) is here: https://github.com/aralroca/skin-cancer-detection-tfjs/tree/d0d288c84919410dd422a1a19de7b207b6f49000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` is of type `int32`. You can cast it to `float32`.

```
 pretrainedModel.predict(image.cast('float32'));
```

Comment: Finally I solved with `image.toFloat()`. I guess is the same. Thank you!